# Combine two images (.JPG) using PHP GD

Tags: php, image, gd, jpeg, watermark

I can't find a solution to this. I want to add 20px empty space to this image:
http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/419/78317401.jpg

and then paste this watermark at the bottom (on the blank space)

So the output would be:

http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/4554/wynik.jpg

I don't want to stretch it.

**EDIT**

Did it with WIdeImage. Rly simple.

Comment: Hi, how you managed this? plz share the code. I just want to append another image at the bottom of an image. It shows as a watermark when i use merge method in WideImage but i want to add image in extra spacing. Plz help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wide image api http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/ 
Check out one of their this demo may be that help you
[Merge](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/demo/index.php?demo=merge&output=preset%20for%20demo&colors=255&dither=1&match_palette=1) and 
 [Resize](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/demo/index.php?demo=resize&output=preset%20for%20demo&colors=255&dither=1&match_palette=1)

Answer (score 19):

1) Load both images with

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

2) Get 1st image height and width with

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php

3) Create larger image with height+20

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php

4) Copy the first image and the second image to the larger image

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

5) Save it

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

6) Done

Comment: Your solution helped me write my own very simple library code to do what i called image appending. Thank you.